# How does Grails know to apply a "layout" to pages it renders?

Tags: grails, layout

I've been going through the book "The Definitive Guide to Grails" (Rocher/Brown) and in Chapter 04, this mysterious thing called a "layout" just appeared with no explanation. (And there's no "layout" in the index. As far as I know, it's never explained.)

How does the system know to "inherit" the pages from layout/main.gsp? There's nothing about "layouts" in the index, and it seems to have just appeared.

On their sample app, a simple store site, the URL mappings for the / homepage say

```
  "/"(controller:"store")
```

and store controller's empty "index" closure

```
package com.g2one.gtunes

class StoreController {

    def index = {
    }
}
```

simply tells it to render store/index.gsp

The store/index.gsp just has a few lines of HTML; no layout gets included with any directive

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="layout" content="main">
        <title>gTunes Store</title>
        <g:javascript library="prototype"></g:javascript>
    </head>
    <body id="body">
        <h1>Your online music store and storage service!</h1>
        <p>Manage your own library, browse music and purchase new tracks as they become available</p>
    </body> 
</html>
```

When I run the sample the page shown for "/" isn't just this simple HTML, it's the contents of "layouts/main.gsp" with this information magically inserted inside it.

I don't see how the information in layout/main.gsp gets applied to the page, how the elements get mixed together. I've been following through the book page by page and this functionality just "appeared" with no explanation.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The `<meta name="layout" content="main">` tag includes the layout in the gsp page.

You can view the `grails-app/views/layouts/main.gsp` to view and modify the layout. You can copy `main.gsp` to `mymain.gsp`, modify it, then change layout entry in the gsp page to reference `mymain.gsp` instead of `main.gsp` and experiment with customizing your layout preserving your ability to easily back out your changes.

Grails uses sitemesh under the covers (like it uses hibernate and spring) to do view layouts. There is a `web-app/WEB-INF/sitemesh.xml` configuration file in the project directory as well. This particular file isn't that helpful, but it references a class in the groovy project if you wanted to deeply understand how grails is using sitemesh (this probably isn't necessary).

Comment: Thanks! It was staring me right in the face. I didn't think to look in a "meta" tag when all the other grails directives looked like <g: !

Answer (score 15):

Here's your directive:

```
<meta name="layout" content="main">
```

main.gsp contains `<g:layoutHead>` and `<g:layoutBody>`, where the `<head>` and `<body>` content of the index.gsp are folded into the layout to create the final page.

Answer (score 6):

One recent trick that appears to work, if you name your layout to match your controller it appears (in Grails 2.3.4 at least) to automatically use that template.

For example, my controller:

```
// grails-app/controllers/myapp/HomeController.groovy
package myapp
class HomeController {
    def index() {
        [ myvar: "Test" ]
    }
}
```

my layout:

```
// grails-app/views/layouts/home.gsp
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <g:layoutBody />
  </body>
</html>
```

my view:

```
// grails-app/views/home/index.gsp
<p>${ myvar }</p>
```

renders using the home layout.

Also, you can specify a layout for all your actions in a controller like this:

```
class HomeController {
    static layout = "someotherlayout"

    // actions will render using grails-app/views/layouts/someotherlayout.gsp
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I got bitten by this when an AJAX-loaded gsp was automatically wrapped. There was a layout with the controller name.